# Piecewise function not evaluating in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, piecewise, discontinuity

Perhaps it's something obvious, but why does this simple piecewise function (as well as other conditionals) not evaluate in `NDSolve`:

```
fcnP[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0.4 < FractionalPart[t] < 0.6},
   {0, FractionalPart[t] >= 0.6}, {0, FractionalPart[t] <= 0.4}}]

temp = NDSolve[{y'[t] == fcnP[t], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 5}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.1][[1]]
```

If I fit an interpolating function to `fcnP`, I get the correct solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I think this is a bug, and you should report it to Wolfram Research.  It turns out that `NDSolve` does process `FractionalPart`, but it seems to do it incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `NDSolve` dos not know how to expand `FractionalPart`.  `PiecewiseExpand` benefits from the addition of an assumption giving the interval of integration:

```
temp = NDSolve[{y'[t] == PiecewiseExpand[fcnP[t], 0 <= t <= 5], 
   y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 5}, MaxStepSize -> 0.1]

ListLinePlot[y /. temp]
```

[image]

Here's another reformulation that works (no need for `MaxStepSize` either):

```
fcnP[t_] := Floor[t + 0.6] - Floor[t + 0.4]

temp = NDSolve[{y'[t] == fcnP[t], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 5}]
```

---

*Addendum: Evidence of a bug*

```
ClearAll[fcnP];
fcnP[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0.4 < FractionalPart[t] < 0.6}}];
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y'[t] == fcnP[t], y[0] == 0}, 
   y, {t, 0, 5}, MaxStepSize -> 0.1, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[foo]];

nf = state@"NumericalFunction"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the numerical function, we see the `FractionalPart` in the right-hand side has been replaced by an expression $(1+s)/2$, where $s$ is `` NDSolve`s$nnn `` and `nnn` is a module number (`` NDSolve`s$1299443 `` in my run).  The value of $(1+s)/2$ as a function of `t` is shown in the blue graph; the gold graph shows the value of the right-hand side of the ode (which should be equivalent to `fcnP[t]`). The only time the RHS is `1` is at `t == 0`; however, it should be zero then.  It is also clear that $(1+s)/2$ is not periodic like `FractionalPart`.  It seems to me that there is a bug with how this ODE is handled.

```
Table[
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, t];
   With[{
     s = (1 + 
         First@NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[
           state@"SolutionData"["Forward"], "ID"])/2,
     rhs = First@NDSolve`EvaluateWithSolutionData[nf, 
        state@"SolutionData"["Forward"]]
     },
    {{t, s}, {t, rhs}}
    ],
   {t, 0, 5, 0.01}] // Transpose // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Comment: Another possibility is to define `fcnP[t_?NumericQ] := ..`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, but the discontinuity is not handled efficiently.  This is better: `fp[t_?NumericQ] := FractionalPart[t];
fcnP[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0.4 < fp[t] < 0.6}}]`, as good as `PiecewiseExpand`, but the `Floor` version takes the fewest steps.

Comment: Thanks @CarlWoll, this is what I also just found worked.  The above problem is just a toy example of a more complex function that is difficult to use piecewise on.  I've used ?NumericQ approach for Minimize and other optimization functions.  It appears that NDSolve has change from many years ago, and now places greater importance on symbolic interrogation of the ODE.  It seems that discontinuous functions like Max and FractionalPart require more explicit handling if the ODE is left in symbolic form.  Thanks also MichaelE2.

Comment: This is a bug for Mathematica 12.0. For Mathematica 11, I don't have this bug.